# Session state enableSessionState issues in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, web-config, session-state, httpmodule

I get the following error in the production environment

> Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the configuration\system.web\httpModules section in the application configuration.

The following things I have tried as of now

- Checked `machine.config` and `web.config`, both have `enableSessionState="true"`
- Added `enableSessionState="true"` to pages in `web.config`
- State module is also added in `<httpmodules>` section
- Even tried setting `enableSessionState="true"` in page directive

Note: When I try to debug the code in Dev environment, everything works fine as it should.

Can anyone help me out getting over this issue, I just can't figure out a way out of it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, could you please provide snapshot of your web.config file. It would be very helpful to users facing same issue.

Comment: Sorry buddy, it's a very long time since I had built this application, so no I don't have the config file now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does your session state config look like? You probably want to be set up to use inproc session handling.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Comment: Oh god, you are seriously a life saver .. I had no `<SessionState>` module present in my config. Added it and the error is gone. thanks a tonne for this link

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late response but I just want to add how I fixed the same problem.

First I want to emphasize that I'm using web forms, not MVC - this may not work for MVC.

I created a web form that contained the class **ContactUser** and I created my own constructor so it looked like:

**public ContactUser(String to, bool isUser)
{
...
}**

And in this I tried to access a session variable:

**String user = Session["username"]**

It turns out that you **CANNOT** use the session state in the constructor of a class, but you can use it in other functions that you write and in the **protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)** procedure. So once I moved session state out of the constructor into the page load procedure everything worked :)!

Hope this helps anyone that runs into the same problem :D!